# Is it possible to find the height of a custom Button while inflating it?

Tags: android

I have created a custom button class which extends AppCompatButton. While inflating the view i want to get the height and modify it and the corners. I am able to achieve it if I make changes in all the places where I have used the custom button. But is it possible to make change in the custom button class and reflect it in other places ?

```
int height = getHeight();
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
if (Configuration.getInstance().getFieldRoundCorner() >= height) {
    drawable.setCornerRadius(height / 2);
} else {
    drawable.setCornerRadius(Configuration.getInstance().getFieldRoundCorner());
}
setBackground(drawable);
```

The getHeight() is always 0

Comment: You cannot get the actual height until it's been measured and laid out. Generally, inside the `View` itself, the easiest and most straightforward way to do that is to override `onSizeChanged()`.

Comment: I am able to set the textColor, background color etc.. but not the custom corners

Comment: I'm not sure what that means in reply to my comment.

Comment: Nothing just thinking for a way to manage it in a single class

Comment: Move that code into `onSizeChanged()`. You won't even need to call `getHeight()` there. The height is passed into that method.